# ComboBox nested properties in DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to understand why this works:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Server.Connections}" DisplayMemberPath="ConnectionName" Margin="91,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279"/>
```

But this does not:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Server}" DisplayMemberPath="Connections.ConnectionName" Margin="91,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279"/>
```

The reason for this is because I want to bind the `SelectedValue` property of `ComboBox` back to my model, but I can't unless I can access `Server` as a whole.

Comment: Use SelectedItem. When item source is bound to Servers then the object is Server object with Many connections, and it doesn't know which name to show/display. Binding to Connections then there is a property ConnectionName which is also working

Comment: Thank you - shouldn't the fact that I have specificed "Connections.ConnectionName" therefore it will know which to display? But doesn't.

Comment: No! Assume you have server object, and this server has 3 connections, now which name should it show ?

Comment: OK that is starting to make sense, but then how is ItemsSource="{Binding Server.Connections}" any different? This works as expected.

Comment: Your DataContext has a Server property, this server has a collection of Connections. So that is why you can bind to Server.Connections. Means each items in the ComboBox is going to be a Connection object. If you on the other hand bind to Server, then there is only one server object in your ComboBox and DisplayMemberPath cannot convert Connection.ConnectionName to any property in the server object.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) states:

> Gets or sets a path to a value **on the source object** to serve as the visual representation of the object.

This property refers to a property path on the item type of the bound collection.

```
<ComboBox Name="cboServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Server.Connections}" DisplayMemberPath="ConnectionName" Margin="91,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279"/>
```

Now, the first variant binds a collection of `Connection` objects (I assume, may be a different type), namely the `Server.Connections` collection. The `Connection` type exposes a property `ConnectionName` which can be specified as the member to display in the `ComboBox`.

If `Connection` had a property e.g. `MyProvider` of type `Provider` that exposed a `Name` property, then `DisplayMemberPath="Provider.Name"` would be perfectly fine, too.

```
<ComboBox Name="cboServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Server}" DisplayMemberPath="Connections.ConnectionName" Margin="91,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279"/>
```

The second variant is different, because it binds a collection of `Server`. If this is not a collection, you will get a binding error in your output, regardless of the `DisplayMemberPath`.

Let us assume it is a collection of any type. This type then has a *collection property* `Connections` with objects of type `Connection` that again have a property `ConnectionName`. The display path has no way of knowing, to which concrete item in the `Connections` collection you refer. So which `ConnectionName` should it display, the first, the second, the 42nd?

The collection itself, which is a `List<Connection>` or `ObservableCollection<Connection>` or anything else does not expose a `ConnectionName`, since it is not a `Connection`. Those are **different types**, hence the property path is invalid.

You can confirm this yourself by refering to an element explicitly, which can be done using an indexer or slash in the binding syntax, see [Binding path syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-path-syntax) for reference.

```
<ComboBox Name="cboServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Server}" DisplayMemberPath="Connections[2].ConnectionName" Margin="91,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279"/>
```

This would display the `ConnectionName` of the third `Connection`. Your examples are **not equivalent**.